# For-Loop on Pointer: Does it move the whole address range?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I have this bit of code:

```
int count_x(char* p, char x)
{
  if (p == nullptr) return 0;

  int count = 0;

  for (; *p != 0; p++)
  {
    if (*p == x)
    count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

The input is in this case a char-array:

```
char v[] = { "Ich habe einen Beispielsatz erstellt!"};
```

Since I am currently looking into CPP with the book "C++ the programming language - 4th Edition" I got the code from there and am currently trying to figure it out.

When stepping through it, I noticed that the for loop moves the memory address in increments of one. This is not very surprising to me, but the following question arose and I couldn't find an answer yet: 
Does this loop reduce the overall memory range or is the whole range being moved?

Since to my knowlege you use a "block" in whole for storing such a char-array (or any type of array), I guess it is the later since I don't see anything reducing the boundries.
But with that "knowledge" I have to ask: Doesn't this cause major issues as it would be theoretically possible to read parts of the memory the programm shouldn't have access to?

Will this be something I have to keep in mind when dealing with (very) long arrays?

Comment: "Does this loop reduce the overall memory range or is the whole range being moved?"  I don't know what you mean by that.  None of your memory is being "reduced" or "moved," the loop is just iterating over every byte until it finds a 0 byte.

Comment: If no zero is found it will continue on, yes.  This is why we use constructs like std::string, which are a bit safer.

Comment: I see that in `for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` the for loop moves the number in increments of one. This is not very surprising to me - but does it reduce the overall number range or is the whole range being moved?

Comment: I think you mean "move over" not "move"

Comment: I suspect your misconception might stem from this: `p++`. This does _not_ modify the actual array in any way, instead you should view `p` as a separate variable containing the adress to an element of the array. `p++` simply increases the adress to the next element in the array. The actual array elements stay where they were allocated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C and C++, `"strings like this"` are implicitly nul-terminated.  That means they end with a `char` whose value is `0` or `'\0'` (same thing).

So this loop:

```
for (; *p != 0; p++)
```

advances `p` until it reaches a point where `*p` is `0` -- the end of the string.

If `p` does not point within a nul-terminated buffer or string, the loop will indeed move over memory beyond the end of the memory buffer it started in. This kind of error is common and relying on strings being nul-terminated results (indirectly) in a lot of buffer overruns, security holes, and generally crashing and memory corrupting programs.

To get around this, C++ offers alternative ways to store and interact with strings of characters, including `std::string`.  These do not rely on the properly positioned nul terminator to work, although much C-style code they interact with may.

And in C++17, string view provides a non-owning low-cost way to refer to a bounded size string with no nul terminator.

Comment: I will tick your answer as you not only hit my missconception on the head but also describe what happens if i wouldn't check if this is a nul(l)-terminated string.
Thanks for that! But to state the fact: Boty you and Rakete1111 provided very good answers, thanks to you both!

Answer (score 4):

You are not moving anything at all. That's where your confusion comes from. Your code is perfectly safe for very very long strings, don't worry. (Apart that `count` may overflow...).

You are right that `p` is incremented in every iteration of the loop, but that doesn't mean that anything is being *moved*. You are only modifying the value of the pointer `p` (and `count`). That's it. Effectively, you are traversing your RAM.

You are right however that you might read in memory that you don't own, but that is the callers fault because `count_x`'s preconditions require that you pass in a null-terminated string, and if you don't, well, you get undefined behavior for accessing memory you don't own. That's why you should use `std::string` instead of `char*`, which is guaranteed to be null-terminated (if you use C++11 or higher).

Comment: This is a hard one :) Rakete your answer is awsome, thank you for that, with your explanation I think I understand pointers a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

No problem with (very)long array. Because count_x(), you pass the address of the first char of array. So no overhead for any length of array. You can you the index with point to traverse on all the array. Look like

```
unsigned int count_x(char* p, char x)
{
  if (p == nullptr) return 0;

  unsigned int count = 0;

  for (unsigned int i=0; i<strlen(p); i++)
  {
    if (p[i] == x)
    count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```